# Responding to a file download request when the file doesn't exist in the server

Tags: java, spring, rest, download

I have created an API call to download file using spring boot as follows :

```
@GetMapping("/files/{filename:.+}")
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFile(@PathVariable String filename) {
    Resource file = fileStorageUtils.load(null, filename);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; "
                        + "filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"").body(file);
  }
```

It works perfectly when the file exists. But when the file doesn't exist then an end of file exception is thrown and the postman(I am using postman to make API requests) request is waiting for the resource for a long time. Is there any way to handle this case so that the client will get a proper response if the file doesn't exist or the requests resource is a folder.

Comment: What about checking if the file exists in your code?!

Comment: I have tried that. But if the file doesn't exist then what should be the response I should give to the client?

Comment: That's the point: you have to define what you want to return to the client. Maybe a 404 makes sense. It's up to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if file exists and if not return something like:

```java
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
```

Comment: This did the trick. I was using the wrong headers to handle the case. Thanks